# Proper collection structure for firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So the app has users (Firebase authentication)

Each user has some settings, and then a collection of json "stuff".

My thought is to have each user be their own root collection, then have a settings doc inside of that, and the also the data collection.  With the reasoning being if I have to delete someone and their data it's just deleting the root with everything inside?

Am I thinking about this the right way?  I don't want to get 2 years in and need to refactor because it's unmanageable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might run into a dead-end if you decide to manage your indexes later, because they require specific names of collections and document fields, and your collections will be named after your users' UIDs.

I ran into similar trouble when I used dynamic document fields, so I had to wrap them into a "myDynamicFields" field, and use that in my indexes.

```
// firestore.indexes.json
{
  "indexes": [],
  "fieldOverrides": [
    {
      "collectionGroup": "myCollection",
      "fieldPath": "myDynamicFields",
      "indexes": []
    }
  ]
}
```

Just like I wrapped my dynamic fields in a "Map" field, you could wrap your settings in a `userSettings` collection, and have a document for each user. The same thing for your "data": a `userData` collection, and a document for each user. Then, to delete a user, you would have to delete two documents.

Comment: See this here is some quality information. So you're saying the index is like a path from the root and if the root collections are userids, it's un-indexable?  So the solution is 2 root collections, "usersettings" and "data" and have the data section contain a userid property?

Comment: For example, if there's a "hugeField" field in the data of your users, you would want to exclude it from the automatic indexes. With my proposal, you'd say "please exclude the hugeField field from the documents of the userData collection". There's no equivalent if collections are UIDs.

Comment: @SteveMcNiven-Scott It's not un-indexable. If you had a collection named after every UID, the documents inside it would be properly indexed, but you just wouldn't be able to describe custom instructions for the indexes.

Comment: Adding a userID field in your documents would be necessary if you wanted to use the UID in more specific queries. If all your queries are just "bring me the settings and the data of user_x", you just get `userSettings/user_x` and `userData/user_x`.